# Execute non-blocking process remotely

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am using `paramiko` to run a command on remote server. This execution is initiated from a `django` website. I would not want the django website to be waiting while the command on the remote server is running i.e. I do not care what happens once the process is initiated.

How can I run this command in a non-blocking manner from the website? I had used `paramiko` once and did notice that `exec_command()` waits for the remote command to complete before returning the control to the callee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is perfect for this.  The docs explain how you can run commands in the [background](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/local_commands.html#background-and-foreground), and how to integrate with [paramiko](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/remote.html#paramiko-machine).